# How to assign int value which is saved as a point in draw rectangle to point?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
point.X = midpoint.X
point.Y = midpoint.Y - value.Height
Dim rc As New Rectangle(New Point(point.X, point.Y), value.Size)
rects1.Add(rc)
temp.X = midpoint.X + value.Width
PictureBox1.Invalidate()
no_clicks += 1

nPoint(i) = New Point() {point.X, point.Y}
nSize(i) = New Size(value.Width, value.Height)
i += 1
```

I have a point  variable  which is a drawing point of a rectangle.I have declared another array of point as DIM npoint() as point so that i can assign the rectangles value to it.Problem is it is saying value of integer cannot be converted into system.srawing.point.

Comment: You can use whatever names you like but it is strongly recommended that you use plural names for arrays and collections. `rectangles` for a collection of `Rectangle` values and `points` and `sizes` for arrays of `Point` and `Size` values. I don't really understand why people don't find this sort of thing obvious. They seem determined to use cryptic names as though programming requires it. Short, cryptic names used to help back when you used to have to type them out every time but nowadays, with Intellisense and the like, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```vb
nPoint(i) = New Point() {point.X, point.Y}
```

is obviously wrong. Judging by this:

```vb
nSize(i) = New Size(value.Width, value.Height)
```

which is the line that follows it, that first line should be this:

```vb
nPoint(i) = New Point(point.X, point.Y)
```

That said, `Point` and `Size` are both value types, so there's no point to creating new instances from parts of existing instances. Just use the existing instances and copies will be created:

```vb
nPoint(i) = point
nSize(i) = value
```

Comment: *"It ain't working"* is not a description of a problem. Use your head. If we are going to help you solve a problem then we have to know what that problem is. You didn't bother telling us where the problem was in the first place. That line would have caused the error you described and I've told you how to fix it. If there's a different problem then you need to actually describe that problem, which includes telling us EXACTLY what happens and where it happens. Update your question with ALL the relevant info.

Comment: We also have the `value` variable that both has a `Size` property and is directly assigned to a `Size` variable. This is technically possible if you know how to create implicit conversions... but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, this is what you are doing

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim npoint() As Point
    Dim i As Integer
    npoint(i) = New Point(3, 4)
End Sub
```

You array has no elements so you cannot assign value to an element.
To fix this just change to a list.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim npoint As New List(Of Point)
    npoint.Add(New Point(3, 4))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to draw attention to the `value` variable in these two excerpts:

```
Dim rc As New Rectangle(New Point(point.X, point.Y), value.Size)
```

and

```
nSize(i) = New Size(value.Width, value.Height)
```

We don't get to know which `Rectangle` constructor overload you're shooting for, but the one where `value.Size` is a `Size` struct seems reasonable. We also don't get to see the declaration (type) for the `value` variable, but it seems unlikely (though not impossible) it both has a `Size` property and an implicit conversion to `Size`. In other words, one of the two lines is wrong.

This isn't the only error in this code. It's clearly part of a loop. Why don't you edit the question to show the *whole loop*, including setup. That might let us give you a much more complete answer.